# Accompanist webview loads initially and then goes blank

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am using Accompanist Webview for loading webview in my compose application. For some urls the webview is loading initially and goes blank after loading. Anyone faced the same issue? Please help

tried `webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true` and `webView.settings.supportZoom()` but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the issue by adding the following to AccompanistWebViewClient

```
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }
```